# Connect airflow to Spark job with Spark submit Operator

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

I would like to run my Spark job in Airflow. From the link https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator/index.html, I am not sure to understand correctly the sentence:
"This hook is a wrapper around the spark-submit binary to kick off a spark-submit job. It requires that the “spark-submit” binary is in the PATH or the spark-home is set in the extra on the connection."
I have my SPARK_HOME env variable but
What is spark-submit binary exactly? Is it the .py file with the Spark job?
The other solution seems to be adding something in the extra of the connection in the Airflow webserver UI. What should be added in that case?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
The error I got is:

```
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,817] {base_hook.py:89} INFO - Using connection to: id: spark_default. Host: localhost, Port: None, Schema: None, Login: None, Password: None, extra: XXXXXXXX
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,821] {spark_submit_hook.py:325} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master localhost --name airflow-spark --queue root.default /home/ubuntu/market_risk/utils/etl.py
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,874] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/', '/home/ubuntu/.local/bin']
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,874] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - 
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,874] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - Did you install PySpark via a package manager such as pip or Conda? If so,
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,875] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - PySpark was not found in your Python environment. It is possible your
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,875] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - Python environment does not properly bind with your package manager.
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,875] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - 
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,875] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - Please check your default 'python' and if you set PYSPARK_PYTHON and/or
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,875] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON environment variables, and see if you can import
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,875] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - PySpark, for example, 'python -c 'import pyspark'.
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,875] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - 
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,875] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - If you cannot import, you can install by using the Python executable directly,
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,875] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - for example, 'python -m pip install pyspark [--user]'. Otherwise, you can also
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,875] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - explicitly set the Python executable, that has PySpark installed, to
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,876] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - PYSPARK_PYTHON or PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON environment variables, for example,
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,876] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - 'PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 pyspark'.
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,876] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - 
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,878] {spark_submit_hook.py:479} INFO - /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/spark-submit: line 27: /bin/spark-class: No such file or directory
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,909] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - Cannot execute: spark-submit --master localhost --name airflow-spark --queue root.default /home/ubuntu/market_risk/utils/etl.py. Error code is: 127.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py", line 187, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self._application)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py", line 405, in submit
    self._mask_cmd(spark_submit_cmd), returncode
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master localhost --name airflow-spark --queue root.default /home/ubuntu/market_risk/utils/etl.py. Error code is: 127.
[2020-12-07 01:12:58,912] {taskinstance.py:1194} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=market_data, task_id=spark_submit_job, execution_date=20201207T010725, start_date=20201207T011258, end_date=20201207T011258
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py", line 187, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self._application)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py", line 405, in submit
    self._mask_cmd(spark_submit_cmd), returncode
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master localhost --name airflow-spark --queue root.default /home/ubuntu/market_risk/utils/etl.py. Error code is: 127.
```

Edit:

I had 2 installations of spark, one manual (located at `/opt/spark`) and the other with pip. I removed the pip installation. So now the spark installed in `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin'` is not a problem anymore but Airflow still does not locate the other manually installed spark.
(I am still able to do a `spark-sumbit file.py` directly in the folder where the project is stores.
The new error is:

```
[ 2020-12-07 09:52:06,591] {base_hook.py:89} INFO - Using connection to: id: spark_local. Host: local[*], Port: None, Schema: None, Login: None, Password: None, extra: XXXXXXXX
[2020-12-07 09:52:06,593] {spark_submit_hook.py:325} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master local[*] --name airflow-spark --queue root.default /home/ubuntu/market_risk/utils/etl.py
[2020-12-07 09:52:06,599] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'spark-submit': 'spark-submit'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py", line 187, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self._application)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py", line 395, in submit
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'spark-submit': 'spark-submit'
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: @acushner I put the bin where spark_submit is located in the extra params fo Airflow UI but I still have the error. `{"queue": "root.default", "spark_home": "/opt/spark/bin", "spark_binary": "spark-submit", "namespace": "default"}`

Comment: @delalma try using capital letters for spark_home?

Comment: @mck from the Airflow log `Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/', '/home/ubuntu/.local/bin']` I understand that it does not look for the spark_home in the right location. But the spark_home is set to `/opt/spark/bin` in connection extra of Airflow. Unfortunately changing the connection extra from `"spark_home": "/opt/spark/bin"` to `"SPARK_HOME": "/opt/spark/bin"` does not solve the issue